# .replace all variables in string

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I want to replace all the words that match with a variable in a string, but it doesn't work. I use this code:

```
var findStr = "hello hi, test, hi";
var textSearch = "hi";
findStr = findStr.replace(textSearch,'<span>'+textSearch+'</span>');
```

It has to change the color of `hi` but only the first `hi` changes, the second one doesn't.

Comment: try using `replace(/hi/g)`, so that it's checked globally rather than just the first instance. Or `var textSearch = /hi/g`

Comment: See this [**JS Fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/uWa6M/)

Answer (score -3):

The replace method is what you're looking for.

For example: someString.replace("String you want to replace", "with this string")

Comment: I use this, but I want to replace a variable with the same variable but with a span tag around it, now it only change the first `hi` but I want it change both.